# Sheet to ListBox1 to Another Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, forms, listbox, spreadsheet

There is a very simple ListBox1 that displays data from Sheet5. Along with the code for displaying data from Sheet5, is a code that saves data to another sheet (Sheet9). My problem is, putting the data on the right row and column as per ListBox1 display.

This is the image of ListBox1 display from Sheet5:

[image: image 1]

This is the Raw data image of Sheet5:

[image: image 2]

This is the Raw data text of Sheet5:

```
Month       || Color    || Time
August      || Red      || 0:00:12
August      || Blue     || 0:00:02
September   || Blue     || 0:00:03
October     || Yellow   || 0:01:00
October     || Green    || 0:00:10
```

This is the Raw image of Sheet9 (to where the ListBox1 data are saved [temporarily - because I have a desired Sheet9 output]):

[image: image 3]

This is my whole form code:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
With Worksheets("Sheet5")
    Dim c As Range
    Dim i As Long
    For Each c In .Range("A2:A100")
        With Me.ListBox1
            .ColumnHeads = True
            .ColumnCount = 3
            .ColumnWidths = "75;75;75;75"
            .AddItem
            .List(i, 0) = c
            .List(i, 1) = c.Offset(, 1)
            .List(i, 2) = Format(c.Offset(, 2), "hh:mm:ss")
            i = i + 1
        End With
    Next c
End With

    Dim shT As Worksheet, cT As Range
    Set shT = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet9")
    Dim nT As Long
    shT.Range("B2: M2").ClearContents
    shT.Range("B3: M3").ClearContents
    'shT.Range("B4: M4").ClearContents
    'shT.Range("B5: M5").ClearContents
            
    For nT = 1 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        'LOCATE
        Set cT = shT.Range("1:1").Find(Me.ListBox1.List(nT, 0), , xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not cT Is Nothing Then
            cT.Offset(1, 0).value = ListBox1.List(nT, 1)
            cT.Offset(2, 0).value = ListBox1.List(nT, 2)
        End If
    Next nT
End Sub
```

This is my current result for my code above. Red marks below are not displayed while green marks are displayed in ListBox1. Row 1 in this sheet is manually coded as well as Column A. This is not really my desired Sheet9 output. I am just showing the current output of the code I am using.

[image: image 4]

This is my desired output below as per ListBox1 display, is this possible? If this is, what should be changed in the code above to save in Sheet9 this way? Still Row 1 and Column A are manually coded (in other words, only the dynamic time will be saved in the sheet according to the correct month and color displayed from ListBox1):

[image: image 5]

Thank you so much in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next way. It uses arrays, working mostly in memory and being fast even for larger ranges:

```
Sub ExtractColorTime()
  Dim shT As Worksheet, rngHead As Range, rngCol As Range, lastR As Long
  Dim mtchR, mtchC, arr, arrLst, nT As Long, rngRet As Range
  
  Set shT = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet9")
  lastR = shT.Range("A" & shT.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
  Set rngHead = shT.Range("B1:M1")       'headers range
  Set rngCol = shT.Range("A2:A" & lastR) 'colors range
  
  Set rngRet = shT.Range("B2:M" & lastR) 'the range where to return
  rngRet.ClearContents
  arr = rngRet.value 'place the range in an array to be returned at once
  
  arrLst = ListBox1.List 'place the list box intems in an array for faster processing
            
    For nT = 0 To UBound(arrLst) 'iterate between the list array rows
        mtchR = Application.match(arrLst(nT, 0), rngHead, 0) 'match the header column (month)
        mtchC = Application.match(arrLst(nT, 1), rngCol, 0)  'match the color row
        If IsNumeric(mtchR) And IsNumeric(mtchC) Then 'if buth matches exist:
            arr(mtchC, mtchR) = Format(arrLst(nT, 2), "hh:mm:ss") ' place the well formatted time in its correct position
        End If
    Next
    
    'drop the array content at once:
    rngRet.value = arr
    
    MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

Comment: @CDP1802 Ups... I (initially) missed a month and the range was ending in column L:L. I fount the missing one and placed it in its position, but forgot to update the range. I will do it now. Thanks!

Comment: hi, wat variable is rngRet? i declared rngRet As Long but there is an error that says Object Required

Comment: @Shiela It must be a range... I had to simulate something to test it. I did  not use a list box on a form. I used a sheet one. Declared and set. The declaration or the range was on code lines I deleted. Put it back now...

Comment: let me try, be ryt back....

Answer (score 4):

### Pivot Data

[image]

- IMO, you're facing an XY problem i.e. you're using the list box as the 'middle man' to pivot the source to the destination. You should do this by simply pivoting the source data.

**Main**

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Return the values from the source data range
    ' in the source data array ('sData').
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Sheet5")
    Dim strg As Range: Set strg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion ' table
    Dim sdrg As Range
    Set sdrg = strg.Resize(strg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1) ' data
    Dim sData() As Variant: sData = sdrg.Value
    
    ' Pass the source data array to the 'PopulateListbox' method (procedure).
    PopulateListbox sData
    
    ' Reference the destination table range (has headers).
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Sheet9")
    Dim dtrg As Range: Set dtrg = dws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion ' table
    
    ' Pass the source data array and the destination table range
    ' to the 'PopulateSheet9' method (procedure).
    PopulateSheet9 sData, dtrg
    
End Sub
```

**The Help - List Box**

```vb
Sub PopulateListbox(Data() As Variant)

    With Me.ListBox1

        ' Do these 3 only once!
        .ColumnHeads = True
        .ColumnCount = 3
        .ColumnWidths = "75;75;75;75"

        Dim r As Long

        For r = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
            .AddItem
            .List(r - 1, 0) = Data(r, 1)
            .List(r - 1, 1) = Data(r, 2)
            .List(r - 1, 2) = Format(Data(r, 3), "hh:mm:ss")
        Next r

    End With

End Sub
```

**The Help - Pivot**

- Note that a more efficient solution would be to replace the `Application.Match` 'functionality' with writing the months and colors to dictionaries to be searched for the column and row indexes respectively.

```vb
Sub PopulateSheet9(sData() As Variant, ByVal dtrg As Range)
    
    ' Determine the number of rows and columns
    ' of the destination values ('Time').
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = dtrg.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim dcCount As Long: dcCount = dtrg.Columns.Count - 1
    
    ' Reference the 'elements' of the destination table.
    
    ' Column Labels
    Dim drgMonths As Range: Set drgMonths = dtrg.Resize(1, dcCount).Offset(, 1)
    ' Row Labels
    Dim drgColors As Range: Set drgColors = dtrg.Resize(drCount, 1).Offset(1)
    ' Values
    Dim drgValues As Range:
    Set drgValues = dtrg.Resize(drCount, dcCount).Offset(1, 1)
    
    ' Clear previuos values data.
    drgValues.ClearContents ' to preserve the 'Time' formatting (not '.Clear'!)
    
    ' Write the matching values to the destination values array.
    
    Dim dData() As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To dcCount) '
    ' In this case, the same as 'dData = drgValues.Value')
    
    Dim DateIndex As Variant, ColorIndex As Variant, sr As Long
    
    For sr = 1 To UBound(sData, 1)
        DateIndex = Application.Match(sData(sr, 1), drgMonths, 0)
        ColorIndex = Application.Match(sData(sr, 2), drgColors, 0)
        If IsNumeric(DateIndex) And IsNumeric(ColorIndex) Then
             dData(ColorIndex, DateIndex) = sData(sr, 3)
        End If
    Next sr

    ' Write the values from the destination array to the destination range.
    drgValues.Value = dData

End Sub
```

Comment: this is really great...thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Please try.

```
    Dim shT As Worksheet, cT As Range, cC As Range
    Set shT = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet9")
    Dim nT As Long
    shT.Range("B2:M1000").ClearContents
    For nT = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        'Locate month
        Set cT = shT.Range("1:1").Find(Me.ListBox1.List(nT, 0), , xlValues, xlWhole)
        'Locate color
        Set cC = shT.Range("A:A").Find(Me.ListBox1.List(nT, 1), , xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not (cT Is Nothing Or cC Is Nothing) Then
            shT.Cells(cC.Row, cT.Column).Value = ListBox1.List(nT, 2)
            ' OR
            ' cT.Offset(cC.Row - 1, 0).Value = ListBox1.List(nT, 2)
        End If
    Next nT
```

Comment: Let me try... brb...

Comment: this is almost perfect.  what's missing is that, the Red data which has 0:00:12 is not put in  the August column.also tried the other way below the commented 'OR, August Red 0:00:12 is not saving. we are close....

Comment: i mean, we are close to the desired output....

Comment: Use 'For nT=0' , I thought u don't need it.